# How to use a module which includes another module in Fortran?

Tags: module, fortran

I want to do something like this:

main.f90 uses module A and module B.
module_A.f90 is independent. 
module_B.f90 uses module A.

My code is like this:

main.f90

```
include "module_A.f90"
include "module_B.f90"

program MAIN
use A
use B
write(*,*) Array(I)

end program MAIN
```

module_A.f90

```
module A

integer, parameter :: I = 10

end
```

module_B.f90

```
include "module_A.f90"

module B

use A

real*8 :: Array(I)=1d0

end module B
```

However, the error information shows:

```
Error: module_A name 'module_A' at (1) is already being used as a MODULE at (2)
```

It seems that I can't use a module to cite another module.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

(Note: it is not the problem of missing "contains" because it doesn't involve subroutine or function)

Comment: Why do you use `include`instead of `use` ?

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for improvement suggestion. Do you mean that `include module_A.f90` should be `include "module_A.f90"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

when you included modA.f90 and modB.f90 in main.f90, since you already included modA.90 in modB.90, then your main.f90 look like this:

```
module modA
...
end module

module modA
...
end module

module modB
use mod A
...
end module

program 

...
end program
```

Since in fortran you can't have two unitwith the same name, the compiler fails with the error you see because you declared two module modA.

## Fixing with use statement (recommended)

modA.f90

```
module modA.f90
...
end module
```

modB.90

```
module modB
use modA
...
end module
```

main.f90

```
program main
use modB
use modA
...
end program
```

However `use`statement needs to deals with dependencies, so `modA.90` must be compiled before `modB.f90`

```
gfortran -o main modA.f90 modB.90 main.f90
```

## Fixing with include statement (depreciated)

I do not recommend this solution, but for the sake of completness, it is provided.

### First answer

modA.f90

```
module modA.f90
...
end module
```

modB.90

```
module modB
use modA
...
end module
```

main.f90

```
include modA.f90
include modB.f90

program main

use modB
use modA
...
end program
```

In this case, since `include` is like copy-pasting, we only need to compile the program

```
gfortran -o main main.f90
```

### Second answer

modA.f90

```
module modA.f90
...
end module
```

modB.90

```
include modA.f90

module modB
use modA
...
end module
```

Since modA is already included, no need to do it again

main.f90

```
include modB.f90

program main

use modB
use modA
...
end program
```

Again we only need to compile the program

```
gfortran -o main main.f90
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realize that "include" does nothing but paste extra code to the file. Actually, just compiling the module first would be enough to "use" them in the main program.

Comment: It may be useful to read paragraph 3.4 of [Fortran Standard](https://wg5-fortran.org/N1601-N1650/N1601.pdf)